# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthInstance' of undefined at signOut

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, google-signin

I am integrating Google Sign-In in my asp.net web app. Sign-In Option works well but sign out in throwing the above mentioned error.

Reference Link of implementation : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Have anyone faced the same issue or has an fix to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30984812/