# `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signOut' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signOut' of undefined

On this line: `auth2.signOut()`

I do NOT have the google signin button on the page below.
I also tried executing function `signOutGoogle`, but that too results in an error.

Top of page my page in `<head>`:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MYAPPIDPLACEHOLDERWHICHIFILLEDOUT.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

Before `</body>` tag I have:

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function onLoad() {
    console.error('onLoad executed.');
    var auth2;
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
           client_id: 'MYAPPIDPLACEHOLDERWHICHIFILLEDOUT.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        });
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    });  
           
    //check if url contains ?signout=true
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.toString().indexOf('?signout=true') != -1) {
        console.error('param found');

        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.error('User signed out');
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

For some reason `ga` is called (which I don't do explicitly myself) and failing, what's happening here?

I already checked here:

- [TypeError: gapi.auth2 undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815870/typeerror-gapi-auth2-undefined)
- [gapi is not defined - Google sign in issue with gapi.auth2.init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144874/gapi-is-not-defined-google-sign-in-issue-with-gapi-auth2-init)
- [HTML PHP google single sign on signout will throw "Cannot read property 'getAuthInstance' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945798/html-php-google-single-sign-on-signout-will-throw-cannot-read-property-getauth)
- [How to check if user is logged in or not with "Google Sign In" (OAuth 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083568/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-or-not-with-google-sign-in-oauth-2-0)

**UPDATE 2**

Now I'm getting error

> Uncaught Error: ia

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

I tried removing calling noload from the script call and then add it to `document.ready` to then call `signout` function, but then even with @Vishal's code the API is not yet available:

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script></body>`

And:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.toString().indexOf('?signout=true') != -1) {
            console.error('onLoad executed.');
            var auth2;
            gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: 'MYAPPIDPLACEHOLDERWHICHIFILLEDOUT.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                }).then(() => {
                    auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                        console.error('User signed out');
                    });
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript code should be like below, and in the code, I have added the logout execution in the then() section of the init action. so logout code only executes once init is back with a response from the server.

```
function onLoad() {
    console.error('onLoad executed.');
    var auth2;
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
           client_id: 'MYAPPIDPLACEHOLDERWHICHIFILLEDOUT.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        }).then(() => {
           auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
           //check if url contains ?signout=true
           var url = window.location.href;
           if (url.toString().indexOf('?signout=true') != -1) {
              console.error('param found');

              auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                   console.error('User signed out');
              });
            }
         }).catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
         });
        
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! One small follow-up question: do you know why after I'm logged in, never sign out and return to the same page one day later, I'm still signed in? Does Google not auto-expire a session after X hours? And if not, is there a way to do this myself?

Comment: @Flo Thanks for your upvote, actually you are using onload=onLoad in the script tag so it will always init the session first and it will log out the user when there is matched URL found. so maybe you need to call the onLoad function when the user clicks on Login action maybe should be a button in your application so init will be executed once and not every time when page load.

Comment: Sure thing, I think we're almost there :) Please check my update 3, because when not using onload to check and not wanting to execute onload each time, the availability of Google's API becomes an issue again. Can you help?

Comment: *friendly bump*

Comment: @Flo Yes, please? I am checking for the issue you mentioned in your last comment so will update to you here.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely that your code is calling the `signOut` function before the `auth2` variable is defined. Based on your code, the callback from `gapi.load` will not execute immediately, and, because JavaScript is compiled, the

```js
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.toString().indexOf('?signout=true') != -1) {
    console.error('param found');

    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
    console.error('User signed out');
    });
}
```

part of your code is being called while `auth2` is still `undefined`. Try putting it inside your callback, like so:

```js
function onLoad() {
    console.error('onLoad executed.');
    var auth2;
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
           client_id: 'MYAPPIDPLACEHOLDERWHICHIFILLEDOUT.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        });
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
           
        //check if url contains ?signout=true
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.toString().indexOf('?signout=true') != -1) {
            console.error('param found');

            auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                console.error('User signed out');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this I still get that same `Uncaught Error: ga` error as you see in the screenshot above

Comment: is it when using the `signOutGoogle` function? It tries to use the `auth2` variable, which is defined in the `onLoad` function, so it cannot use it.

Comment: Actually no, that entire function I never call, I removed it from my post for clarity. I added update 2, where I now get `ia` is undefined. It's related to `at qx.a.<computed> [as signOut] (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=ili,ipu:339)`, so it looks like a function in the Google library, but I have no idea where (other than in `onLoad`) this signout function is called...

Answer (score 0):

```
  function onLoad() {
    console.error("onLoad executed.");
    var auth2;

    const oauthLogin = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gapi.load("auth2", function () {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: "MYAPPIDPLACEHOLDERWHICHIFILLEDOUT.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        });
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      });
    });

    oauthLogin.then(() => {
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("?signout=true") != -1) {
        console.error("param found");
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
          console.error("User signed out");
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

You can assign a promise to a variable and execute some code after it's resolved like this.
There are multiple ways for achieving that, check [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) reference.

by the way you don't need to parse window.location.href to String because it `location.href` is a stringifier that returns a USVString which fits for your purpose.