# Integrating Google Sign-In into my web app problem

Tags: javascript, c#, google-signin

I have some problems to integrate Google Sign-In into my web application. I managed to log-in but when tried to log-out I get the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAuthInstance').

I  am using this :
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: Some code please?

Comment: checkout this answer (if not checked) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945798/html-php-google-single-sign-on-signout-will-throw-cannot-read-property-getauth